# Swift: implicitly unwrapped variable works but not force cast it to the same type. Why?

Tags: swift

I have a `MyCell` that is a type of UIView. I could create them as below.

```
private let myCell: MyCell! = MyCell.createFromNib()
myCell.callingFunction()
```

This shows that `myCell` is not `nil`.
However, if I want to explicitly cast it as below, and restart the same code (which means `myCell` would not be `nil`, since the same code wasn't nil previously)

```
private let myCell = MyCell.createFromNib() as! MyCell
myCell.callingFunction()
```

It will crash with error

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I thought that should work as well. What's the different between the two?

FYI the `createFromNib` function declaration is as below

```
class func createFromNib<T: UIView>() -> T?
```

FYI, I'm new to iOS and Swift

Comment: Implicitly unwrapped variables can be nil as well. It will crash only if you try to read the variable and if its nil.

Comment: What type is 'createFromNib' declared to return, in the first code snippedt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicitly unwrapped optionals are actually (unsurprisingly), under the hood, optionals! The only advantage IUO's bring is the fact that you don't need to write the `!` (forced unwrap) operator, the compiler does this for you.

Which means that `nil` values are acceptable values for IUO's. Which is why `MyCell.createFromNib()` is allowed to be assigned to `myCell`, even if the function might return nil under some conditions.

On the other hand `MyCell.createFromNib() as! MyCell` is evaluated before the assignment, and `as!` always results in a non-optional value, unless applied to a value that can't be cast (nil or another hierarchy). Thus, it's not the assignment that fails, it's the forced cast operation that triggers the fatal error.

`MyCell.createFromNib() as? MyCell` would've worked just as well, with the difference that instead of crashing this could've introduced a silent bug. Now, it's up to you to decide if this is preferable or not. I would've gone the semi-crash solution: a crash of Debug, a silent fail on Release. This way potential issues could be caught during the QA phase, however, if not caught they would not crash the production app.

```swift
let cell = MyCell.createFromNib()
assert(cell != nil, "Oops, something bad happened, please call the Avengers")
myCell = cell as? MyCell
```

Comment: Hi Cristik, I have updated my question. The subsequent call to `myCell` shows that it is not `nil`. So I am confuse why the second one crash...

Comment: @Elye you should also add the declaration for the `MyCell.createFromNib()` function

Comment: Thanks Cristik. I now understand this fully. Well explained. I'll upvote it. Looks like my confusion comes from the different result from `MyCell.createFromNib()`, based on what it is assigned to. This is most strange. Anyway, I think I don't deserved a -3 for this question :( . I stated I'm new to iOS and hope to get some understanding. If you think my question is valid, perhaps you could help upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: @Elye I think the downvotes were due to the lack of information (aka code) in your question rather that the fact that you're a beginner in Swift. BTW, now that you found the reason of the crash you should add it as an answer, instead of editing it into the question.

Comment: I found the culprit of the issue. I don't think the answer fit this question, as it is unrelated (e.g. why `createFromNib` generate `nil` some times and not the other time). Anyway, I update the question to make it clearer with the relevant info.

Answer (score 3):

- In the first example you declare the variable as implicit unwrapped *optional* but you are only going to **write** the – obviously optional – result of `createFromNib` into this variable which could be `nil`.
- In the second example you **read** the result of `createFromNib` while casting it. If it's `nil` it crashes.

Comment: Hi vadian, I have updated my question. The subsequent call to `myCell` shows that it is not `nil`. So I am confuse why the second one crash...

Comment: Thanks, your answer helps, and I upvote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

`private let myCell: MyCell!`

Here, myCell can contain either *nil* or value of type *MyCell*
So it is perfectly alright to assign *nil* value to this.
(However, it will give an error if you use it when its value is *nil*.)

---

`private let myCell = MyCell.createFromNib() as! MyCell`

Here, you are trying to convert *nil* to type MyCell which is definitely an error.

---

**Note:** I think `MyCell.createFromNib()` is returning *nil* in your code for both cases.

Comment: Hi Ankit, I have updated my question. The subsequent call to `myCell` shows that it is not `nil`. So I am confuse why the second one crash...

Comment: Thanks Ankit. Your answer helps me as well. I upvote your answer too.